# Getting the Context of the enclosing object

Tags: java, android, eclipse

New to Java. I am trying to create an explicit Intent to launch send the user to a new tab and pass some data to it. The problem I *think* I am having is getting the Context of the parent object that I can pass to the Intent Constructor. "This" is not correct. The onCreate code is below. Any pointers to examples would be helpful

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quickactivity);

    final Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
    goButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, TimeActivity.class);

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use:

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), TimeActivity.class);
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<MyClassName>.this
```

instead. Replacing  by the actual class in which this method resides